# Should PHP FastCGI be running multiple instances on windows?

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012

Im running PHP under iis 8.5 on Windows Server 2012. The server runs asp.NET without a hitch. Pages are rendering in well under a second, but PHP is not running so well. It takes upwards of 40 seconds for a page to load. Can often take 10 seconds just before the server responds to the request. The ASP code is still running fine, so it is most definitely down to PHP. I checked task manager and i can see CPU spike whenever a page is loaded. It looks like Fast CGI is running 7 times. All of these consume CPU when a page loads. Is this normal behavior?

I installed php using the web platform installer https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx. This installed x86 PHP 5.3. The server is x64, but i cant see how the 32 bit version is going to be cripplingly slow like this.

[image]

Comment: How many people are using PHP on the server? A process for each user could be expected. As for PHP running slow, that could be an issue with the installation but it tends to be more of an issue with poor code in my experience (18+ years). Since you are stuck with 32 bit it would be beneficial to know what PHP is expected to be doing. Large data manipulation is slow, especially on Windows. PHP doesn't even recommend running on Windows

Comment: the volume is very low at the moment. The site is also just a standard enough wordpress install with a premium theme so it is unlikely this is the cause. Are there any typical issues to look for with a bad php install? I have php 7 setup and i will chance using this, but it may cause some issues

Comment: How much memory is set for PHP to use? Does the server have enough memory to handle x users each using x memory and ASP.Net? Does ASP.Net feel the load of PHP? As for WordPress, this shouldn't be an issue. Could you test with a default WordPress theme and see if the site runs normally? You would be surprised how many "premium" themes are utter crap... Can you profile a request for PHP to see if it's not MySQL slowing down PHP?